# Не применяются стили в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны

Есть тема the7dt и её дочерняя the7dtchild. В the7dtchild в style.css меняю стили `#bottom-bar .mini-nav { margin-right: 40px; }` , но в итоге применяется `#bottom-bar { margin-right: 40px; }`. А бывает вообще ничего не применяется и в Chrome DevTools в Sources в файле этих стилей вообще нет. А когда в админ панели этот файл открываю, то там всё то, что я и писал. Почему так? Как исправить?

Comment: вы пробел ставите? он не нужен т.е."#bottom-bar.mini-nav". Может в этом дело...

Comment: Нет, мне нужно к дочернему элементу применить, а не к #bottom-bar с классом .mini-nav

Comment: Да, простите. Проверил на простом документе, всё работает. Может у вас перетираются значения? К bottom-bar у меня ничего не приминяется.Тут скрин: https://yadi.sk/i/ZG1d2sKeqysBz

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нет. В инспекторе стили не отображаются даже вообще.

Comment: Еще вариант - криво стили подключены, раз в sources нету. Попробуйте подключить эти стили к другому документу и проверить...

Comment: Попробуй в самом низу в файле style.css просто добавить #bottom-bar .mini-nav { margin-right: 40px; }

Comment: Я так и делаю. Ни у родительского шаблона, ни у шаблона-потомка не меняются стили. Все что я пишу - ничего не применяется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создание дочерних тем по кодексу WordPress, по моему скромному мнению, имеет недостаток. Проявляется он как раз в ошибках переписания родительского css. Я рекомендую вам поступить следующим образом:

1) Отключаем родительский css
В файле `functions.php` родительской темы ищем строку, подключающую css, нужно узнать ее id. В моей теме "NatureSpace" это выглядит следующим образом:
[image: Подключение стилей]

id файла стилей - `naturespace-style`

Далее в `function.php` вашей(дочерней темы) прописываем следующий код(пример для моей темы):

`/*
 * отключение стилей родительской темы
*/
function give_dequeue_plugin_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style('naturespace-style');
    wp_deregister_style('naturespace-style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','give_dequeue_plugin_css', 100);`

2) Вместо подключения родительского стиля с помощью `@import...` копируем код файла `style.css` и вставляем в свой. В дальнейшем вам не придется переписывать значения, просто изменяйте уже существующие. Этот метод, в первую очередь, избавляет от проблем с `!important` в родительских темах и путаницы с приоритетностью в классах.

*Дополнительно:* Используя код, приведенный выше, вы можете отключить любые ненужные вам стили и скрипты(для скриптов `style` меняем на `script`)